# AJAX method does not call Controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-mvc

I am new to AJAX/Spring MVC. I have one index page which is showing team name. on selecting a team, I want to display players name dynamically in the same page i:e *index.jsp*. Here are my codes.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#teamName').on('change', function(){ 
            $('#playerNames').show();
            function getPlayersList(){  
                $.ajax({
                    type : "GET",           
                    url: "Player/getPlayersList",
                    contentType : "application/json",           
                    dataType : 'json',
                    contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',           
                    success : function(json) {      
                        $.each(json, function(key, value) {
                            if (value != null && key == 'playersList') {
                                var players = String(value);
                                var array = players.split(",");
                                for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                                    if(array[i] != ''){                                     
                                        players.append($('<option/>').val(array[i]).text(array[i]));
                                    }
                                }                               
                            }
                        });         
                    }
                });
            }
        });     

    </script>
```

**Controller class**

```
@Controller
public class Player {   
MappingJackson2JsonView view;      
@ResourceMapping("/")
public View getPlayersList(){
    view = new MappingJackson2JsonView();       
    List<String> playerList = new ArrayList<>();        
    playerList.add("Shehwag");
    playerList.add("Sachin");
    playerList.add("Dhoni");
    playerList.add("Virat");        
    view.addStaticAttribute("playersList", playerList);
    return view;
}
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<servlet>
  <servlet-name>player</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
  <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>  
<servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>player</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

**player-servlet.xml**

```
 <context:component-scan  base-package="controller" />     
 <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">  
    <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/" />  
    <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />  
</bean>
```

**where am i doing wrong?. Please Help.**

Comment: You have only defined the function `getPlayersList`, You need to invoke it.

Comment: @Satpal. thanks. but where should i call getPlayersList() ?

Comment: in JS you have `url: "Player/getPlayersList"`, but in Controller class you have `@ResourceMapping("/")`, which mean url must be "/"

Comment: @Optio..I tried this also but did not work.is there any problem/missing in web.xml / player-servlet.xml ?